# How to repent from accidentally eaten pork?

Tags: food, tawba, pork, mistake

Yesterday, I have unknowingly eaten a burger that most probably had pork inside.

I was at school, we just won the house cup, we were celebrating, and then they started serving us burgers.

I asked them what the contents of it was, and they replied with 'vegetables and salami'

Back then I didn't know very much about salami and since I only ever ate the halal beef ones, I though this would be the same and accepted it.

Later after I took a bite, I asked again what it was to really make sure that it wasn't pork, and they replied with 'salami' so I was led to believe that I was eating the same thing as back then while I was most likely consuming pork.

I have asked for forgiveness in my prayer, and I would like to know if there is anything else I should do.

Also, when I was young, about 8-9 years old, I remember being alone at home while very hungry, to the point where my mouth was watering and drooling.

I looked around the house for anything to eat and came across a packet of snack biscuits that I liked, but this time it seemed that my parents bought the wrong one and bought one with pork flavour by accident.

I couldn't find anything around the house a small child like me could eat at the time, and took the packet unwillingly.

I looked around more to make sure there was nothing else I could probably eat to suppress my hunger, and ate a few of the biscuits while absolutely hating it and unwillingly.

Only 2-3 or 4 biscuits in(each very small ones) I looked at the packet and realised that there was also a pizza flavoured one inside and I never realised it due to the packaging being the same colour.

I remember that I stopped eating immidiately and maybe spit out the content in my mouth and ate the other one instead after throwing the previous biscuits in the bin.

I didnt think too much of it back then, but now that I know the severity of the situation and have gone into a similar situation again, I remember the incident and am panicking quite a bit.

I would like to know if there is any way to repent for my sins of that time?

Comment: See this answer here, i didn't had previlige to comment thats why i am adding as an answer. http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/29814/15642

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a little alarmed that you are panicking about "sins" you made as a **child**!

*What kind of monster do you think God is?*

First of all, a sin is only a sin if you **intended** to make that sin, knowing what you were doing, which can hardly apply to your recent misfortune, least of all when you were a child. Innama al a3malou bin-nyiate : the deeds require intention. Be it a good deed or a bad deed.

So rest assured, there is nothing for you to repent from.

And second, please keep in mind that God is just and fair! He would not punish a *child* for eating because he was hungry! Or, indeed, for anything else. Until he reaches puberty.

Comment: Addendum [on forgiveness in Islam](http://en.islamtoday.net/artshow-299-3181.htm)

Comment: As you say, it's all about the intention. It's also good to mention (even though it's out of topic) that if a person for instance is in an island where he cannot find any food but pork, he would be allowed to eat that to survive.  And if he refuses to eat it in that situation and he then dies of hunger it is likely that it will be counted as a sin because we are responsible of ourselves.

Comment: Thanks, that is an excellent point. I will look for the references. Unless you have them. If not I know the hadith's, I just need to get my hands on it.

Comment: I could be back with references if you wish inshaAllah . But the Hadith you quoted (innama al3amalo biniyyat) is an excellent reference too. The intention while eating is to survive and not to sin.