# Lately found out eating pork

Tags: shirk, pork

Asalamu alaik Jamah!    My name is Abdul Rauf from Ghana. Please my Muslim friend ate pork without his notice and don't know how to do and don't know if Allah will accept his prayers again. Please help us to know what do. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't your friend the one who asked [this exact same question](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/29754/i-have-accidentally-eaten-pork/29755#29755) just a few days ago ?

Comment: What I wonder is why you used the shirk tag. One should be careful with using those terms.

Answer (score 1):

Walaykum Assalam

Do not worry, as Allah(swt) forgives all as long as one asks for forgiveness and repents!

If he has done so unintentionally without knowing or didn't have the intention of eating it, then it is not a sin and he has no need to worry.

If he has done so intentionally, then he must pray for forgiveness and swear that he shall not do such an act in the future, then, Allah will forgive.

Allah will forgive anything as long as we have the intentions to be forgiven and as to not do that wrong again.

I've been in a similar situation recently, but I have done the necessary steps and asked for forgiveness even though I didn't know I was eating pork for the sake of my mentality.

May Allah guide you.

Comment: May Allah Richly Bless You

Comment: Yeah. I agree with the answer. It is actually a simple and admirable answer. God Bless Him.

Answer (score 0):

Wa alaikum salam
Sahih Al-Bukhari Hadith 1.1 Narrated by Umar bin Al Khattab

> I heard Allah's Messenger (saws) saying, "The reward of deeds depends
>   upon the intentions and every person will get the reward according to
>   what he has intended.

Allah says in the Holy Quran Chapter 6 Surah Anaam verse 54:

> When those come to you who believe in Our Signs, say: "Peace be on
>   you! Your Lord had inscribed for Himself (the rule of) Mercy. Verily
>   **if any of you did evil *in ignorance*, and thereafter repented and
>   amended (his conduct), Lo! He is Oft-Forgiving, Most Merciful.**"

Allah says in the Holy Quran Chapter 3 Surah Ale Imraan verse 135-136:

> **Allah likes such good people very much, who, if ever they commit a
>   base deed or wrong their own soul by the commission of a sin, remember
>   Allah instantly, and ask for forgiveness from Him for their
>   shortcomings**. For who, but Allah, can forgive sins? (And Allah loves
>   those) who do not knowingly persist in the wrongs they did. These will
>   be rewarded with forgiveness from Allah, and with Gardens beneath
>   which canals flow, and they will reside therein forever! How excellent
>   is the reward of those who do good deeds!

So there is no need ot worry just seek forgiveness of Allah on this matter as Allah says in quran and everything is ok.

Comment: May Allah Richly Bless you