# Is it sinful to make a dua to ask Allah to reject another person's dua?

Tags: halal-haram, dua

Not long ago, I would make a dua or wish to Allah to not only curse but to not grant the duas of the intended victim in the afterlife.

I asked this question before but O was adviced to make it more clear.

It is not just me but I am sure many does it. The thing is, does Allah listen to the dua of the men more than women's dua. And does Allah grant the more better Muslim dua over the average Muslim?

Long ago, this boy who used to bully me said that he is making a dua in which it will make Allah not to grant any of my wishes in the afterlife.
He also said that since he is a boy, I cannot undo this curse of his. Will Allah apprive of the boy's dua because his gender is higher?

Also, I am not sure if this is the whsipering of tbe devil but... do pious people control our duas. I have been envious of the Prophet SAW because of the thought that he would ask Allah not to grant a dua he may not like. Since Allah is close to Muhammad SAW, I think he might do it for him.

Is this the devil's whispering?

I am sad because I am mentally veing trialed. I need help.

The thing is, does ANYONE has the right to have a say in if Allah rewards someone even the Prophet SAW himself? I cursed that boy mainly due to anger, hate, and greed.

Did the Prophet SAW did not hate his enemies that cursed and bullied him like the boy in my life?

I know I should have a good opinion of Allah but I cannot sleep well and I have been crying.

I was told by many Muslim men that because I am a woman, their duas will rule and control over me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, despite the question in the title being about Islam, the remainder is more about personal advice.

Answer (score 0):

This is revolting:

1- If someone tells you God listen to him more than he does to you, it is simply stupid of him, but it is wrong for you to believe that. How can you believe that a human being can pretend to knowing **anything** about what God does or does not, or who God prefers ? All someone can tell you is "Quran says this, Sunna says that", but what God does or knows or wants is entirely out of anybody's realm of knowledge.

2- Only *consider* believing someone (anyone) if he or she gives evidence (verses, hadiths). Simply saying that God answers men more than women ought not to convince you.

3- God is not a wand that anybody can wave, nobody can "curse" anybody, whatever their gender.

4- I don't know how long ago was "long ago" but any wrong you did before puberty is not counted in Islam (you can see [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/29754/i-have-accidentally-eaten-pork) and others on this site).

5- "do pious people control our duas?". NO, absolutely not! Islam is not Christianity, it has no system of saints that you can ask for favours, *nobody*, not even the prophet, can block your dua or has any incidence on what who God punishes (read [more here](http://main.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=0&tTafsirNo=73&tSoraNo=3&tAyahNo=128&tDisplay=yes&UserProfile=0&LanguageId=2) - Note that the prophet will be granted the honour to intercede on judgement day, but only for forgiveness).
God **alone** chooses to take your dua into account. God does not need secretaries keeping track of duas.

> And when My servants question thee concerning Me, then surely I am
> nigh. I answer the prayer of the suppliant when he crieth unto Me. So
> let them hear My call and let them trust in Me, in order that they may
> be led aright. (Quran 2:186)

of which you can read [many tafsirs on this site](http://main.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=0&tTafsirNo=74&tSoraNo=2&tAyahNo=186&tDisplay=yes&UserProfile=0&LanguageId=2).

I have read the Quran - and encourage you to do so - and in all such verses as this, that start with "when my servants ask [about something]", the next verse is always "tell them [this and that]".

The above verse is the **only** verse where there is no "tell them". I have heard analysis of this that said it may be to emphasize how important it is to know that there are no intermediaries. Unlike Christians, for example, God alone can forgive and it is not conditioned by your confession to an imam or a priest.

On the contrary, there are instances of people confessing a crime to the Prophet, thinking that it was needed for repentance, and the prophet said "if only you secretly repented [there would have been no need for punishment]" (read [more here](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/215221) if you read arabic).

In conclusion, please think long and hard about the idea that you have of God. He is close, simply talk to him. And you have the great luck of living in the era of Internet, you do not have to believe what you are told simply because it is told by men, you can read for yourself, you can learn for yourself, question everything, and try to live in peace.

Comment: I have been going through the same mental phase. Only I am afraid that the person who might make a bad dua for me is actually very good to his parents, and his parents are immensly  pleased with him, and I have read that Allah accepts the Dua of the one whose parents are pleased with them. Whereas I am nowhere near good to my parents and have done a lot of wrongs with them. So there is always a fear of hopelessness in Dua mixed with jealousy, which is literally making me go insane like this sister above.